# Custom table view cell with rounded edges

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I wish to create a table cell like the following image

[image]

How could this be done via storyboard? My initial plan was to use two different views/labels, And round the edges using `layer.cornerRadius` but this rounds all edges of both views/labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the greenView inside cell's contentView and round it with `cornerRadius` and inside it add the blackView without any rounding as the superview will do the job only make sure

```
greenView.clipsToBounds = true // can be set in IB
greenView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
```

You can also add these 2 views below each other and round top corners of the top and bottom ones of the bottom view with https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners

Comment: I have just tried your way, But sadly the blackView is not rounded on bottoms.. See my updated question for screenshots

Comment: make sure bottom constraint of greenView is set properly at least 10 points from contentview

Answer (score 0):

Embed both views in a container `UIView` and round the corners of the container.

```
containerView.clipsToBounds = true
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```